# ng-repeat items appear before view is completely updated angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in CategorizedItems" 
     ng-if="CategorizedItems.length> 0" 
     class="row customRow itemBorder animated slideInLeft" >
         {{item.name}}
 </div>
```

I show the list of items in above div.

On click of a button, `CategorizedItems` are updated.

i.e

```
$scope.CategorySelected=function(categoryName){
    $rootScope.CategorizedItems =[];
    $rootScope.CategorizedItems = $rootScope.Items.filter(function(obj){
        if(obj.category.name === categoryName)
            return obj
    });

}
```

This method is called.Now, when I go from one class to another, New items appear gracefully but items from previous category appear under the list of new items for a couple of seconds.

Comment: works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/NlDCOOoVybbDHBxXKhY6?p=preview

Comment: @Simran Kaur, are you applying some kind of animation to the list?

Comment: @jjimenez: Yes, animated slideInLeft from animate.css. The problem still exists if I do not apply this animation.

Comment: @SimranKaur could you possibly add a fiddle over here for better understanding of the problem

Comment: Realized that it is not a problem when I do not apply the animation

Comment: So when you don't apply the animtion it works, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in Angular.

Most people do this ...

```
<div ng-if="false">
    don't display me
</div>
```

and then at end of HTML ...

```
<script src=".....angular.min.js">
```

and expect the DIV to not appear. Of course it will initially appear in this scenario since it has no idea what ng-if means UNTIL angular is loaded.
Put your angular script include at top of page.

You may also wish to consider using ngCloak directive or CSS class, which is the documented way of resolving this issue (assuming script tag is at top of page).

If I have real problems with this then I might use $scope.readyToRender boolean variable in my controller to control when to display elements.
e.g. at end of controller code I would set it to true and wrap code in an ng-if='readyToRender'

Comment: None of these fixed the issue. Could you please check the edit. I realized that it's just that new items appear at top of the screen and items from previous category appear for a while under the list of new items